# Store PFUser Object in a PFUser key results in a Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfobject, pfuser

I've been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong for about a whole day now, but I have absolutely no idea why the App always crashes.

The situation is the following:

I've set up a Simple Project with all the required Libraries and Frameworks implemented. I've created several Parse Users with the the following instance method:

```
[self signUpUserWithName:@"nico" withPassword:@"123"];
[self signUpUserWithName:@"gabriel" withPassword:@"123"];
[self signUpUserWithName:@"bruno" withPassword:@"123"];
```

Here you can see the method implementation:

```
-(void)signUpUserWithName:(NSString *)username withPassword:(NSString *)password{

    PFUser* user = [PFUser user];
    user.password = password;
    user.username = username;



    [user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if(!error){
            NSLog(@"User created.");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"User couldn't be created.");
        }
    }];

}
```

This works as expected, the users are created and everything is fine. Now I'm logging in a user and create a PFUser Object to the current User with the following code:

```
  [PFUser logInWithUsername:@"user1" password:@"123"];


    //Fetching Current User
    PFUser* currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if ([currentUser isAuthenticated]){
        NSLog(@"Authenticated");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Not Authenticated");
    }
```

This also works as expected. The user is logged in and I receive a currentUser Object, which is authenticated. Now I'm trying to get the object of a user with a query and if succeeded, assign the resulting Object to the key "myfriends" of my currentUser (creating a One-To-One Relationship).

```
PFQuery* friendQuery = [PFUser query];
    [friendQuery whereKey:@"username" equalTo:@"user2"];
    [friendQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if(!error){
            NSLog(@"%@",object);

            currentUser[@"myfriends"] = object;
            [currentUser save];

        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Failed getting User Object.");

        }
    }];
```

This also works as expected. If I now open my Data Browser in Parse, I can see that a Pointer to the user2 object was assigned to "myfriends".

But If I relaunch the App, a crash occurs. If I assign something else than a PFUser, for example a PFObject with some data on, to the "myfriends" key of the other PFUser, everything just works fine. No crashes, perfect. But If I'm trying to assign a PFUser, it crashes with the following Message:

```
2015-01-19 13:44:09.135 localizr[2320:281655] -[__NSCFBoolean _loadSensitiveUserDataFromKeychainItemWithName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19967eb60
2015-01-19 13:44:09.136 localizr[2320:281655] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFBoolean _loadSensitiveUserDataFromKeychainItemWithName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19967eb60'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x188301e48 0x1989fc0e4 0x188308f14 0x188305cc4 0x18820ac1c 0x1000758a4 0x10006f97c 0x10007f25c 0x10007ecbc 0x10007ead4 0x10000d1f8 0x18cb223d0 0x18cd39230 0x18cd3b9b0 0x18cd3a048 0x190565640 0x1882ba124 0x1882b922c 0x1882b742c 0x1881e51f4 0x18cb1b78c 0x18cb16784 0x10000d4c4 0x19906aa08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help.

Best wishes
Nico

EDIT:
Here's the stack trace you asked for:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xca4e, 0x0000000196d93270 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x0000000196d93270 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
    frame #1: 0x0000000196e31228 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 112
    frame #2: 0x0000000196d0ab18 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 112
    frame #3: 0x0000000195df1418 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 116
    frame #4: 0x0000000195e10b8c libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 304
    frame #5: 0x000000019660c3c0 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 128
    frame #6: 0x0000000195e0dbb4 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
    frame #7: 0x0000000195e0d73c libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 144
    frame #8: 0x000000019660c294 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 44
    frame #9: 0x0000000185df52a4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
    frame #10: 0x000000018a72b78c UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 552
    frame #11: 0x000000018a726784 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1488
  * frame #12: 0x00000001001015d4 localizr`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fd03a68) + 116 at main.m:14
    frame #13: 0x0000000196c7aa08 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

Comment: What does a symbolicated stack trace look like at the time of the crash?  (If you type 'bt' in the debugger console, for example.)

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be resolved with the update to v1.6.3 of the Parse iOS/OS X SDK. Though i have encountered the same problem, i havent updated yet to the new version, so i cannot say yet if it really works...

See [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/802450039810796/) for the official discussion and response.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @luke He has summarised it.  The article's section of significant importance says _"This should now be resolved with v1.6.3 of our iOS/OS X SDK. Thanks for your patience."_ which I think Marius summaries sufficiently

Comment: Since there are given no more details in the link either - apart from the fact that the issue apparently was caused by the buggy interaction between the Parse local datastore and the Parse Facebook utils - i dont know what @Luke was missing...

Comment: @Marius yep. you're totally right. After updating to Parse v1.6.3 several bugs including this one are being resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I removed [Parse enableLocalDatastore] inside my application that was causing the same issue.

Seems to be resolved.